# Search field runs away from the cursor

Tags: bug, top-bar

The search field runs away if you try to select its content to enter a new request. You can keep the mouse button pressed, but it will need to move the cursor much further left...

User profile pages always have some text in the search field.

It is annoying, but funny :-)

[image]

Comment: So... don't start your search from user profile pages?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it happens for me on the Meta and SO question lists, not just on the profile page.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If it is not meant to be used then it shouldn't be visible and active.

Comment: This is probably by design, and isn't a bug. Would you like to propose a feature request?

Comment: Click, ctrl+backspace*3, though I agree. Somewhat annoying..

Comment: @Andrej I meant, if you're finding yourself needing to highlight the userid and number every time, don't search from the user profile page. Or, instead of holding down the mouse button, simply triple-click in the search box; it will highlight the existing text (at least in Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 on Windows 10).

Comment: I would propose a feature request to get rid of the resizing search bar completely. I liked it better when it was always a consistent size.

Comment: Resize to left is annoying for sure. Resize to right may be less annoying.

Comment: You can still highlight it if you drag from left-to-right, and you're quick enough to do it before the animation starts

Comment: As a workaround, you can teach yourself to always type Ctrl+A before typing.

Comment: You could also triple-click to select everything.

Comment: @TotZam Indeed. Any UI element that moves around after the page is done rendering is irritating. That was true of the floating vote buttons, and it's just as true for a text input box.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This happens on every single search page, not just user profile pages.

Comment: I think: Move the profile, notifications, achievements, site list icons back to the left side, have the search bar expand to the right.

Comment: Extend the search bar only after the user types the first character into it.

Comment: @MrLister It's a bug report not a request for a workaround. There are many different widely adopted scenarios how to interact with input elements. None of them should be broken by new fancy features. Ctrl+Backspace, Shift+Home, Ctrl-A, double click, popup menu -> select all, tab navigation, shift+tab navigation, mouse selection, double tap, etc - everything better be working. BTW, the search field comes at wrong position (before "Questions" button) when navigating using tab button.

Comment: @Andrej "Workaround" means "you can use this until it gets fixed". It does not mean "there's something you can do, so it won't need to get fixed". Sorry if you got the idea I didn't agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitly very bad UI design - When clicking onto an input field, the least thing you'd expect is the beast moving away from where you've just seen it. And I don't consider this a "feature" or the fix a "feature request" but rather a fundamental design error.

If the designer insists he wants to grow the label once it's selected (for whatever strange reason, I rarely find myself typing in longer search terms that would exceed the default size of the text box, and after all, that thing supports scrolling...), why doesn't he extend it *to the right*?

Comment: The only thing I've seen that's worse is an input field that expands to the right, pushing over the submit button. There's a site I've used that did that and attempting to click the "search" button causes loss of focus to the input field, shrinks it, moves the button over and....the search is not performed because the button didn't actually receive a click.  Annoys the absolute $h!t out of me every time.  And the change in size isn't even as drastic as what's here on SO, no, it's like 15 pixels and not animated.